# How to ensure a @SpyBean is only used for a given test and not by others

Tags: spring-test, spring-boot-test

I would like for a `@SpyBean` to be used only by one test and not used by others. I use **spring boot 1.4.4**.

I have tried to rely on configurations. I want the spy bean to be used only by `RegenerateTokenOnCollisionIT`.

Here is what I have attempted:

```
@TestConfiguration
@Import(RegenerateTokenOnCollisionIT.Config.class)
public class RegenerateTokenOnCollisionIT extends BaseApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private TokenTools tokenTools;

    @Test
    public void findOrCreateTokensShouldRetryOnCollision() throws PciSecurityException {

        //Will be inserted
        doReturn("someGeneratedToken")
                //Will conflict
                .doReturn("someGeneratedToken")
                //Real method will then be used by retry
                .doCallRealMethod()
                .when(tokenTools)
                .createToken(any(TokenProfile.class), anyString(), anyString());

      ...
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    static class Config {
        @SpyBean
        private TokenTools tokenTools;

    }

}
```

Here is the `BaseApplicationTest` class:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class BaseApplicationTest extends BaseTest {

}
```

and the `BaseTest` class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
public abstract class BaseTest {
...
```

Of course I want the above `Config` class to be added to the existing configuration from `BaseApplicationTest` and `BaseTest` classes but not replace them altogether.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Annotating the test class with @DirtiesContext will mark the application context to be destroyed so that the next test class will recreate it. The new application context shouldn't have the @SpyBean anymore.